# Bash : How to evaluatie variable with a file path with a string litteral of a path

Tags: string, bash, variables, filepath, evaluation

I want to evaluate if 2 paths are equals, but bash interpret `$ZEND_EXTENSION` as a path and tell me there is no such a file or directory instead of evaluating the if statement :

```
ZEND_EXTENSION="/other/path/to/xdebug.so"

if( "$ZEND_EXTENSION" != "/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so" ) then
    echo "It is not there !!!";
fi
```

**output:**

```
jdoodle.sh: line 5: /other/path/to/xdebug.so: No such file or directory
```

Comment: And I missed the formating...

Answer (score 2):

You got the syntax wrong, here's the fix:

```
ZEND_EXTENSION="/other/path/to/xdebug.so"

if [ "$ZEND_EXTENSION" != "/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so" ]; then
    echo "It is not there !!!"
fi
```

Comment: According to an online interpreter, it does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative to using the classic `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`  if

```
if test "$ZEND_EXTENSION" != "/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so" ;
then
    echo "It is not there !!!";
fi
```

check this about [portability of script across shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168255/is-test-or-or-more-portable-both-between-bash-shells-and-between-other-shel)